# requirejs backbone coffeescript router error

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs, router

With Requirejs in Backbone and CoffeeScript,
until here there is no problem,
but when this router executed,
below code console outputs start and finish,
i couldnt console "home"
what is wrong wtih these codes?

I want to enter, home function.

Please Help or Advice,

Thanks.

```
define 'Router',[
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
      'HomeView'
    ],
    ($,_,BackBone,HomeView) ->
        class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router.extend
            console.log "start"
            routes :
                '':'home'
                'home':'home'
            initialize:->
                console.log "init"
            home:->
                console.log "home"
            console.log "finish"
```

Comment: can you link the compiled js?

Comment: @agconti http://jsfiddle.net/yilmazerhakan/rD4C6/

Answer (score 0):

Why have you "extend" after Backbone.Router ?

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router.extend
```

replace with :

```
class AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
```